# Restore branch which is replaced by another branch in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We have two branches staging and production in SVN. Recently I deleted production branch and create production branch from staging branch because there was huge conflicts between production and staging. But now I want to restore production which I deleted. Please let me know how I can restore. I tried restore from following command.

```
svn cp –rREVISION_BEFORE_DELETION https://<REPO_URL>/Production \
 https://<REPO_URL>/Production_restore \
 -m "Restore Production.."
```

But it created `Production_restore` branch from staging by specified revision.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's the only problem, but specifying only path makes SVN thinking that you mean the second production branch. Try to add clarification:

```
svn cp –rREVISION_BEFORE_DELETION https://<REPO_URL>/Production@REVISION_BEFORE_DELETION \
 https://<REPO_URL>/Production_restore \
 -m "Restore Production.."
```